# How use LIKE in Yii query builder

Tags: mysql, yii, query-builder

How build this query with YIi query builder

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE type_item = 2 AND name_item LIke '%name%'
```

I tried so

```
return Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->select('*')
    ->from('{{event_field_variants}}')
    ->where('type_item = :type AND name_item LIKE "%:substr%"', array(':type' => '2', ':substr' => 'name'))
    ->order('variant ASC')
    ->queryAll();
```

But this query get CdbcException.
On Yii documentation are examples only with like or only with simple param.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
->where('name_item LIKE :substr', array(':substr' => '%name%'))
```

Just put it in the variables part?