# how to check, if authenticated user in array from db

Tags: yii

In my DB I have a project table which has

```
  project
  id | title | users |
  1  | First | 1,2,3 |
  2  | Second| 2,6   |
```

how can I check Yii::app()->user->id contained in users field? I want to check, if `true` then show row in gridview.

Which $criteria must I use?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11397700/how-use-like-in-yii-query-builder) and [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/29747-using-mysql-regexp-in-cdbcriteria/). Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LIKE` query for checking your `user id` exist or not in `users column`.

```
$user = Yii::app()->user->id;
$result = Yii::app()->db->createCommand('SELECT * FROM project WHERE users  LIKE "%'.$user.'%"')->queryAll();
if(count($result)){
    //Your other scripts to show in grid view
}
```

If you have a `Project` model `class` then you also can use:

```
$user = Yii::app()->user->id;
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->select = '*';
$criteria->compare('t.users', $user, true);
$results = Project::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Comment: Building queries like this is unsafe as it opens up the possibility of SQL injections. My experience with Yii is that I rarely if ever actually need to use plain old SQL queries, as most can be done with the CActiveRecord methods and other available (and more secure) database classes.

Also see:
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/199/creating-a-parameterized-like-query/

$q = new CDbCriteria();
$q->addSearchCondition('content', $userId);
$projects = Project::model()->findAll( $q );